# How to set delay time to List adapter default animation

Tags: android, kotlin, android-recyclerview, android-animation, android-listadapter

Every thing in List Adapter Works fine. But I want to set delay time while it doing its default animation. It was like super speed. But I need set a delay of 500L

Consider a Page that has Edittext and Recyclerview. When the page open everything works fine. But when user typed any words in Edit Text filter process takes place. After filter I update the list by following code

```
someAdapter.apply {
   submitList(someList.toList())
}
```

Problem is default animation of List adaper is super speed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
recyclerview.itemAnimator!!.changeDuration = 2000L
```

Answer (score 0):

You can edit the following parameters in the `recyclerView` class:

```
init {
    itemAnimator!!.changeDuration = 2000L  //default value: 250 
    itemAnimator!!.addDuration = 2000L  //default value: 120
    itemAnimator!!.moveDuration = 2000L  //default value: 250
    itemAnimator!!.removeDuration = 2000L  //default value: 120
}
```